# Grub Rescue help

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I tried to delete an Ubuntu Partition and now I cant access either of my Operating Systems.
I have tried Several different commands and none of them worked. I always got the unknown Filesystem error with every attempt.

Comment: What is your other OS?

Comment: When you say I cannot access "either" of my OS's, does that mean you still have 2 left because you were triple booting or did you have only Windows and Ubuntu?  If only Windows [Dillmo's](http://askubuntu.com/a/314621/65969) answer will fix your problem.  If you were triple booting or were using Apple's OS, then you need to clarify your question....

Answer (score 1):

What you did is remove Ubuntu without resetting your MBR. To fix this, you need to follow these instructions:

1. Reboot into a Windows CD
2. Choose Repair
3. Choose Command Prompt
4. Type `bootrec /fixmbr` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Type `bootrec /fiboot` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Reboot. Your computer should now boot into Windows XP.
7. Profit!

If you want a full guide on how uninstall Ubuntu, see [this website](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/).